# How to validate a Kerberos ticket against a server in Java?

Tags: java, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

we are using JAAS to enable Single Sign On in a Java application using the Windows Kerberos ticket cache. Our jaas.conf config file looks like this:

```
LoginJaas {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=true
  doNotPrompt=true
  debug=true;
};
```

With this, we can create a Jaas LoginContext and successfully get the user's Kerberos ticket. We send this ticket to out server application using JMI. What we don't manage to do though is to verify on the server that the Kerberos ticket was in fact created by our Active Directory.

At the moment, we do a very insecure validation of the ticket by simply checking if the Server Principal (KerberosTicket.getServer()) name has our domain name in the realm part. But of course, anyone could set up an own Kerberos server with the same realm name and use that ticket to start the application.

One idea I have found was to authenticate against the Active Directory LDAP using the Kerberos ticket. Unfortunately, we use Windows 7 and re-using the Kerberos ticket to authenticate against the LDAP only works when setting a Registry entry (see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html, search for allowtgtsessionkey). This is unacceptable for our users.

Is there any way to validate the ticket against our Active Directory server? I suspect there is a way to check if the KerberosTicket.getServer() ticket equals the ticket of our server, but I have no idea how to do that. UPDATE: KerberosTicket().getServer() only returns a KerberosPrincipal that contains nothing but the server ticket name and realm, so it is not suitable for validation.

Thanks for your help,
memminger

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, the proper way to solve this is by kerberizing your service, which is the whole point of the Kerberos protocol (authenticating clients against servers).  Ticket reuse doesn't work exactly because it'd be a security problem if it did.
A Kerberos service does not need to "log into Active Directory", it just needs to have a shared key with AD.

BTW, to get SSO using JAAS requires having that allowtgtsessionkey set, there's no way around that on Windows.

Comment: Beware that Active Directory user names with latin characters do not work in Kerberos login module in JAAS.  Significant limitation unless the system is US-ASCII only.

Answer (score 2):

As no one seems to really know an answer to this, I suppose we have to make a proper Kerberos service out of our server application. One that logs in to the Active Directory itself and that has the ServicePrincipalName attribute set properly. Kind of like SPNEGO does for HTTP. A good starting point how to do that will be the SPNEGO Servlet filter on SourceForge (http://spnego.sourceforge.net/). http://thejavamonkey.blogspot.com/2008/04/clientserver-hello-world-in-kerberos.html is also a very good example of how to do Service logon.
Unfortunately, this leads to the same problem with the registry key, so I posted a new question on [Is there a way in Java or a command-line util to obtain a Kerberos ticket for a service using the native SSPI API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335896/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-a-kerberos-ticket-for-a-service-in-java-without-modifyin).