# HttpClient Kerberos Keytab authentication without login.conf

Tags: java, kerberos, apache-httpclient-4.x, keytab

I can successfully send and receive HTTP requests to servers with kerberos, following [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientKerberosAuthentication.java?p=820841) and stackoverflow instructions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885323/kerberos-connection-using-http-client) or others, and they all require login.conf. However, I'd like to know if there's anyway to get rid of the login.conf file, and set Kerberos authentication details programmatically.

Comment: Hi; If Vasyl Lyashkevych answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that you want to avoid the login.conf. From the other hand you can see [this tutorial](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/client_keytab.html), where:

```
custom-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab = "file:///c:/spnego-examples/hellokeytab.keytab"
    principal=metis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unless I missed something, the tutorial shows how to create a keytab, and I'm not at liberty to create keytab. The keytab is provided to me and can be stored at different locations.